# Retrieve Specific Columns from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app that gets all the data from the sqlite database and converts it into JSON, but I was wondering how would I be able to do it if I only want to get the data of specific columns?

This is the code I use to get all the data from the SQLite databse and convert it to JSON:

```
  Cursor data = db.getCartItems();
        orderNameArray = new JSONArray();
        data.moveToFirst();
        while(data.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            int totalColumn = data.getColumnCount();
            orderNameObject = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++)
            {
                try {
                    orderNameObject.put(data.getColumnName(i), data.getString(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            orderNameArray.put(orderNameObject);
            data.moveToNext();
        }
        data.close();
```

Thanks in advance for all the insights or help in advance! :D

Comment: show ur db.getCartItems() you can make changes in query for specific columns you want
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm

Comment: Oh yeah haha. I am an idiot, I can create another function to get the specific values I need haha. Thank you sir! You deserve an Upvote :)

Comment: You can also use if statements with `continue` to skip columns you selected if you don't wish to write a custom SELECT statement.

Comment: Well I got it to work already sir, I was just overcomplicating my problem haha. But thanks for the info sir, might check into that for extra knowledge :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch only **selected fields of table**, then use the following query:

```
SELECT Coulmn1, Coulmn2, Coulmn3 FROM TABLENAME;
```

or u want **all data**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;
```

for more info https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, my problem was so simple. I was just overcomplicating it haha.